# Compile PL/SQL stored procedures in SQL developer from external files

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a requirement where I have around 50 stored procedures saved in 50 different files with `.pls` extension in a windows directory. I have SQL Developer installed in the same machine. I want to compile all these stored procedures in SQL developer. Note - I don't want to execute, only want to compile. Please suggest a solution for this.

I have tried this but it didn't work.

1. Created a `compile.sql` file with contents below.

   ```
   @@"U:\Stored_Procedures\PRC_LOAD_TBL.pls";    
   exit;
   ```
2. Created a `compile.bat` file with contents below.

   ```
   sqlplus -s -l <username>/<pswd>@<servicename> 
   @"U:\Stored_Procedures\Compile.sql" ;
   ```
3. Tried to run `compile.bat` batch file but it didn't work.

Also, I tried to run these from SQL Developer directly that didn't work either.

Comment: Open each file and click run script? Or list all the files in a script with `run` or `@` and run that script? What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you need to use SQL Developer, for some reason, or can you simply run SQLPlus? Do you know how to run a single SQL file from SQLPlus?

Comment: Yes, I know how to do this from sqlplus. But my requirement is to do it from SQL developer.

Comment: @NeedBasedLearner why can't you copy paste the file contents into SQL Developer ?

Comment: I have too many files (around 50) to copy paste the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Tried to run compile.bat batch file but it didn't work."

You tried to run a DOS batch file in SQL Developer? I think you're over-engineering this.

All you need to do is open your first script, `compile.sql` in SQL Developer and then click `Run script` (or press `F5` function key).

[image: SqlDeveloper screenshot]

Comment: Brilliant Solution! Thanks very much @APC

Comment: hi, when i hit F5, only the script in the first line runs. it doesn't continue to the next script. would you know why?